# Python WxWidgets : how to add hook called when window close button is pressed

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a Python WxWidgets program, and have a "File->Quit" menu option that calls a quit function that cleanly shuts down my application.  However, the application can also be closed by pressing the 'X' in the top right of the window.  I would like to add a hook to capture that window close event to do my clean shutdown.  How do I do that?

My main window is created with these options:

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ummm

```
def __init__(self,parent,title,...):
      wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnClose)

def OnClose(self,evt):
      print "CLOSE!!!"
      self.Destroy()
```

Comment: Exactly correct. Note that Joran is using the Destroy() method. This is required. If you call Close(), it will call OnClose() recursively and the application will die with a recursion limit error.